# How to pull data from multiple databases via Qt .ui form?

Tags: qgis, oracle-dbms, qt, qt-designer

Using a single .ui form and wthin QGIS, can I show multiple records from another table that is associated with a single polygon?

Table 1 contains planning applications ref
Table 2 contains multiple address associated with one planning ref.

I click on a polygon that has a planning application reference and within the same form, I want to view all addresses associated with it?

I am pulling the information from a non-spatial oracle database and my polygons exist in esri shapefiles.